# How can a program access an IDE hard disk?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, cpu

If I have some device that is connected to a parallel port, and I want to write a program (an OS) that accesses that device, I can't access the device registers directly, but rather I can only access the parallel port registers, and so communicate indirectly with the device through the parallel port.

But I am wondering how can I access an IDE hard disk, can the registers of an IDE hard disk be accessed directly?

Comment: IDE is an old technology that has been rebranded "PATA", are you interested in that or in general about HDDs? PATA drivers can be accessed through legacy ports (0x1f0, 0x170, 0x3f0, 0x370) and in general by scanning the PCI bus and looking at the BARs of the functions marked as Mass Storage Device, IDE. The register layout is fixed, once you know the base address the ATA/ATAPI standard defines the commands. See [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/PCI_IDE_Controller) for a quick introduction and particularly the links section.

Comment: @MargaretBloom: off topic: you seem very knowledgeable about this kind of low level/actual hardware topics, what kind of work/study path brought you to that kind of specialization? Did you write device drivers/OS parts/emulators...?

Comment: Hi @Matteo, I'm mostly self-taught. I spent my teen years fascinated by computers and how they work. For fun, I wrote OS parts but never really did any serious work.

Comment: Oh ok, that's essentially why/when I learnt C++ and Win32, guess I didn't aim low level enough. :-)

Comment: @Margaret Bloom I am interested in all types of hard disks, but currently learning about IDE hard disks. Is an IDE hard disk connected to the PCI bus?

Comment: @John HDDs are connected to controllers, controllers reside on some bus. In the beginning, it was the ISA bus, then the PCI. Now it is the PCIe or some external bus like USB or Firewire. I suggest starting with the legacy IDE interface, as shown in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: @Margaret Bloom Just one last question, I have seen two types of IDE controllers, one type is a separate PCI card, and the other type is part of the motherboard. Is the IDE controller that is part of the motherboard also considered to be connected to the PCI bus (even though it is not plugged to a PCI slot)?

Comment: @John Yes, it appears as a PCI device (it is a PCI device). By default is mapped in the legacy io ports by the BIOS but you can remap it.